# Fail2ban sshd rule is active but not working!

Tags: ssh, authentication, fail2ban

I used ubuntu 22.04 TLS.

`sshd_config`:

```
Port 9401
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE
MaxAuthTries 3
```

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[ssh-9401]
enabled = true
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 60m
action = iptables-multiport[port=9401]
```

`/var/log/auth.log`: empty

`sudo tail -n 2 /var/log/fail2ban.log`:

```
2023-09-01 05:35:10,038 fail2ban.actions        [5552]: HEAVY   Actions: check-unban 20, bancnt 0, max: 20
2023-09-01 05:35:10,038 fail2ban.actions        [5552]: HEAVY   Actions: wait for pending tickets 2 (default 2)
```

Why not block my brute force attack after 3 try!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> `/var/log/auth.log`: empty

If it is empty, how fail2ban shall find the failures, if it is monitoring this log?

Possibly your sshd is logging to systemd journal?
Simply check:

```
fail2ban-regex systemd-journal sshd
fail2ban-regex systemd-journal sshd[mode=aggressive]
```

In this case you have to add `backend = systemd` to the jail (instead of `logpath = ...` or after it).

Basically there is already `sshd` jail, everything you need in `jail.local` would be this:

```ini
[sshd]
enabled = true
backend = systemd
port = 9401
```

(only parameters you need to overwrite).